# auto fill web form with dynamic data

Tags: web, mechanize, autoit

I am trying to create shipping labels for a lot of different customers by filling forms on ups website. Is there a programmatic way of doing this?

It is different from the usual auto-fill web form. Because the name, address, etc. fields aren't filled with "constants". 100 customers needs 100 different forms.

Before I dig into python-mechanize, or autoit IE.au3, is there an easier way doing this?

Comment: Should ne no problem using Autoit. Where is your problem?

Comment: to add to the question: the dynamic data comes from another commerce website. So the task is to extract the shipping data from that website and to fill out the forms on ups website. autoit provides enough support for web form filling, but its html parsing is lacking. Selenium + beautiful soup (in python) are probably the right tool for me.

Comment: In Autoit it really is no problem to grab info from webpages. But anyhow, you found your solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE 2019-09-09: Generally, would no longer recommend FF.au3 unless you're very much into AutoIt or have tons of legacy code. I'd rather suggest using Selenium with a "proper" programming language.

You could check out [FF.au3 for AutoIt](http://english.documentation.ff-au3.thorsten-willert.de/). Together with FireFox and MozRepl it allows for web automation, including dynamic websites/forms.

The feature-set should be sufficient for your task (eg. XPath for content extraction and for filling out forms, but just have a look at the link and you'll get an idea of what it can do). It's also fairly easy to use.

The downside is that it's not the most performant approach and I've encountered a bug, but that doesn't say much. Overall it did work well for me for small or medium-ish projects.

Setup:

- Install AutoIt: https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit-tools/
- Get the FF.au3 lib: https://www.thorsten-willert.de/index.php/software/autoit/ff/ff-au3
- Get an old Firefox version `<v57` or `ESR` (see remarks on ff.au3 page above)
- Install MozRepl: http://legacycollector.org/firefox-addons/264678/index.html

Comment: Can you please describe how can I start with it? What should I have install ? Sorry, If if this was simple question. Actually, i am looking for something like this.

Comment: Added some info on how to install it. However, as of now, I would certainly not recommend FF.au3, but using something like selenium. It's more powerful and can be used with proper languages like Java, but also eg. with Python. The complexity/learning curve is also quite the same as with FF.au3, so unless you're very fond of AutoIt or have legacy code etc., you should no longer use FF.au3.